# Defining command \old|

Tags: macros

I want to let the command `\old|` refer to the command `\|` (which produces the output `||`.) So I do:

```
\let\old|\|
```

LaTeX complains "Missing $ inserted." How can I fix it?

Comment: Use `\def\old#1{\|}` and than you can work with `\old|`

Comment: A command name is (in default setting) either `\<one-char>` or `\<arbitrary-number-of-letters>`. The character `|` is not a letter. I suggest using `\let\oldvert\|` .